# Problems with new command on Rails.vim

Tags: ruby, vim, ruby-on-rails-4, rails.vim

I've installed a plain instalation of Ruby on Windows (using Ruby Installer, so Ruby 2.0) and Rails. Also, I've installed GVim, and, using Pathogen, the plugin Rails.vim.

But, when I try to create a new application, using Vim, the following error occurs:

```
:Rails new MyApp

Error detected while processing Function rails#new_app_command
E118:Too many arguments for function: s:sub
E15: Invalid expression s:sub(&shellpipe, '%s', temp, 'g')
```

In command prompt the application is created without problems.

I already tried to create an empty .vimrc, with only pathogen command.
Also, I acess the plugin documentation throug gVim without problems.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rails.vim is looking for a path to find ruby & rails.  What are you using for a vm?

Comment: None. I just have installed using "Ruby Installer" and "gem install rails". The commands "ruby" and "rails" are working fine and the ruby installation folder is on PATH environment variable. There are another configuration that I should do?

Comment: Use [the plugin's issue tracker](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails).

Comment: In terminal type `which ruby` and post what that says.

Comment: It's a Windows environment, so I used "Where" command. The result is: C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\ruby.exe

Comment: Please use the issue tracker that @romainl gave you. Tim Pope has a defined function called `s:sub()` that only takes 3 arguments but as the error message states it is being called w/ 4 arguments. This is a bug and it is probably supposed to be `s:gsub(&shellpipe, '%s', temp)`.

Comment: Posted the issue on github repo: https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments (by romainl and  Peter Rincker), it is a bug of the latest version of the plugin.

The Issue http://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/issues/344 was posted and solved. An update of my local version solved the problem. Now, everything works fine.